# Finding the minimal polynomial of a polynomial in $n$ variables over a field adjoined by the elementary symmetric polynomials

Tags: polynomials, minimal-polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

I would like to know how you might generally try to find the minimal polynomial so that I can try to do it for a specific case.

The elementary definitions in $n$ variables are defined to be:

$$s_1 = X_1 + \dots + X_n$$
$$s_2 = \sum_{i<j}X_iX_j$$
$$ \vdots$$
$$s_n = X_1\dots X_n$$

Now let $K$ be a field and let $M = K(s_1, \dots, s_n)$. How might you begin to find the minimal polynomials of various polynomials in $K[X_1, \dots, X_n]$? For example, $X_1X_2$?

If $n$ were to equal $2$ then it would simply be the linear polynomial $f(t) = t - s_2 = t - X_1X_2$, but what could we do if, say, $n=3$?

The specific case I want to try to work out is $X_1X_3 + X_2X_4$ in the case where $n=4$, in case there is anything special about it that suggests there may be a slightly rogue way of approaching it.

Overall, I would like to know if there are any techniques for finding the minimal polynomials for these multivariate polynomials over this field over symmetric polynomials.

It is a lot less intuitive than when working over fields such as $\mathbb Q$ since I can just keep applying standard operations until the value ends up in $\mathbb Q$, but in this case I am really struggling to keep track of all the symbols and can't help but wonder if there would be an easier way to do this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notion of a *minimal polynomial* of a *polynomial* or collection of polynomials.  Please give the definition.

Comment: @hardmath I take it to mean a primitive polynomial $f(t)$ in the ring $M[t]$ such that $f(X_1X_3 + X_2X_4$. Basically we're treating the polynomial $X_1X_3 + X_2X_4$ as an element in some field extension of $M$ and trying to find its minimal polynomial over $M$. I just called $X_1X_3 + X_2X_4$ a polynomial because I wasn't too sure how else to refer to it .

Comment: The zeroes will be the orbit under the symmetric group. Example for $n=3$: $$(t - X_1X_2)(t-X_1X_3)(t-X_2X_3) = t^3-s_2 t^2 + s_1 s_3 t - s_3^2$$

Comment: In most cases a polynomial will be transcendental over its field of coefficients.   You seem to have in mind extending the coefficient field by symmetric polynomials of some fixed number  $n$ of indeterminates.  So the problem becomes whether a non-symmetric polynomial can be algebraic over the ring of symmetric polynomials.

Comment: @WimC Sorry, what do you mean here when you say the "symmetric group"? Do you mean $S_n$? I know that since it is irreducible the roots are in the same orbit under the action of the galois group, but how do we know this is necessarily $S_n$? Also, if instead $n=4$, would we have $(t -X_1X_2)(t - X_1X_3)(X_1X_4)(t-X_2X_3)(t - X_2X_4)(t-X_3X_4)$, because these roots are the orbit of $X_1X_2$ under the action of $S_4$?

Comment: Yes. For example for $X_1X_2+ X_3X_4$ and $n=4$ you get $$(t - X_1X_2- X_3X_4)(t - X_1 X_3-X_2 X_4)(t - X_1 X_4 - X_2 X_3).$$

Comment: @WimC Thank you! This makes sense as I was expecting a cubic. However, I am unsure of why exactly we are considering the action under $S_n$. Is this guaranteed to be the Galois group? Is it because $M$ is invariant under $S_n$ so if the splitting field of the minimal polynomial is $M \leq L,$ then $S_n \leq Gal(L/M) \Rightarrow Gal(L/M) \cong S_n$?

Comment: You're overthinking this. The minimal polynomial is clearly invariant under $S_n$ and therefore the set of its zeroes must also be invariant under $S_n$.

Comment: I see that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be a finite [Galois extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension) of $K$ with Galois group $G$, and let $a \in L$ be any element.

> **Exercise #1:** The minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$ is the product $m(t) = \prod_{a' \in \text{Orb}(a)} (t - a')$ where $\text{Orb}(a) = \{ ga : g \in G \}$ is the orbit of $a$ under the action of $G$.
>
> **Exercise #2:** $K(x_1, \dots x_n)$ is a finite Galois extension of $L(s_1, \dots s_n)$ with Galois group $S_n$ (acting by permutation on the $x_i$).

(For the purposes of this calculation the definition of "finite Galois extension" you should use is that $G$ is a finite group acting on $L$ such that the fixed field $L^G = \{ \ell \in L : g \ell = \ell \forall g \in G \}$ is $K$, since this is all we need.)

This completely solves your problem. For example, when $a = x_1 x_2$ the orbit of $a$ under permutation consists of all polynomials of the form $x_i x_j$ where $i < j$ (this is to avoid duplicates, since $x_1 x_3 = x_3 x_1$ and so forth), hence the minimal polynomial has degree ${n \choose 2}$ and is

$$\prod_{i < j} (t - x_i x_j).$$

The exercises imply that the minimal polynomial always has degree the size of the orbit under permutation, which generically has size $n!$ and in general divides $n!$.